# How to include multi jenkins jobs inside one jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, build

I am working on a project, which have many other projects with are dependent on each other. I am making build using Jenkins, but every project is estimated as a different project so when i build projects it fives error. Is there any way by which we can add all projects in one single job(it can have different work spaces in side that job).
And another issue is that when I clone my project from the local repo using Git Plugin. it doesn't clone all the files or data inside those inside files.

Comment: You must to give more details about your projects .. what kind of projects are.. Maven/gradel/ant etc.. more details about your current jobs in jenkis etc.. show the errors you need to resolve ..

Comment: they are gradle projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to include multijenkins jobs question ...

I do not exactly how are your jobs or if this is that you want.

You can create a **pipeline of jobs bases on upstream/downstram relationship**. It's dificult show it here but I'll try.

Fist ->,  You must be clear how is the dependency tree between your projects identifying as firt job,  the project of final of your tree and last job, the project at the top of your tree.

For example:

```
  project4   --> top of the tree has dependency of project3
     project3  --> has dependency of project2
       project1 --> has dependency of project1 
     project2  -->  has dependency of project1
     project1 --> has no dependencies with other jobs
```

Then you can create a new job, following the example,  the first or main job is **project1job**.

Next ->,  Configure the cloning from your git repository in "source code configuration tab".
enter values for Repository URL, Credentials, Branch Specifier etc.

Next -> Configure the gradle goals commands that you want for build, in the "project tab"

Next ->,  Go to the "next actions tab" and add a "trigger/call builds on other projects" and enter the name the following for "Projects to build field" as **project2job**.

-> Save the job.

Next ->  Create the second job of downstream pipeline for the project2

repeating all the steps above. In this job the trigger must call **project3job**

--> The same again Create the project3job. In this job the trigger must call **project4job**

Then when you have all the jobs relations done, you can run the main job, in this case **project1job** and jenkins will follow the secuence and will build all the project in at same time following the dependency tree sequence.

That is an example of the use the upstream/downstram relationship approach, that usually be use to build multiple projects in the same time.